# How to find the average of the differences between all the numbers of a Python List

Tags: python, numpy, average, mean

I have a python list like this,

```
arr = [110, 60, 30, 10, 5]
```

What I need to do is actually find the difference of every number with all the other numbers and then find the average of all those differences.

So, for this case, it would first find the difference between `110` and then all the remaining elements, i.e. `60, 30, 10, 5`, and then it will find the difference of `60` with the remaining elements, i.e. `30, 10, 5` and etc.

After which, it will compute the Average of all these differences.

Now, this can easily be done with two For Loops but in `O(n^2)` time complexity and also a little bit of "messy" code. I was wondering if there was a faster and more efficient way of doing this same thing?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be sorted in descending order? And if it's not, do you want the mean of the *absolute* differences, or do you always want to subtract later elements from previous elements when computing differences?

Comment: @user2357112 For my case specifically, the numbers will be sorted in descending order. However, I think a generic way of solving it could also be computed and might be helpful for people.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'll just give the formula first:

```
n = len(arr)
out = np.sum(arr * np.arange(n-1, -n, -2) ) / (n*(n-1) / 2)
# 52
```

Explanation: You want to find the mean of

```
a[0] - a[1], a[0] - a[2],..., a[0] - a[n-1]
             a[1] - a[2],..., a[1] - a[n-1]
                         ...
```

there, your

```
`a[0]` occurs `n-1` times with `+` sign, `0` with `-` -> `n-1` times
`a[1]` occurs `n-2` times with `+` sign, `1` with `-` -> `n-3` times
... and so on
```

Comment: The base Python equivalent is `out = sum(x*j for x, j in zip(arr, range(n-1, -n, -2)))/(n*(n-1)/2)`.

Comment: And for completeness, n*(n-1)/2 is (n choose 2), which is the number of pairs.

Answer (score 8):

Not as brilliant as @QuangHoang's answer, this answer uses numpy broadcasting to calculate the differences matrix, then average the upper triangle values to get the answer.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([110, 60, 30, 10, 5])

dif = np.triu(a.reshape(len(a),-1) - a)
out = np.mean(dif[dif != 0])
52.0
```

Answer (score 5):

> Now, this can easily be done with two For Loops but in `O(n^2)` time complexity and also a little bit of `messy` code.

No need for the code to be messy.

```py
from statistics import mean

arr = [110, 60, 30, 10, 5]

m = mean(arr[i] - arr[j] for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(i+1, len(arr)))

print(m)
# 52
```

If the array is not sorted, replace `arr[i] - arr[j]` with `abs(arr[i] - arr[j])`.